# Export to Excel by id from table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to export to excel from the table by id

Something like this:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Exports\JobExport;

public function export($id)
{          
     $query=DB::table('applyeds')
     ->where('job_id',$id)
     ->get();
    return Excel::download( $query, 'job.xlsx');    
}
```

Blade: `<a href="{{url('job/export',$job->id)}}" class="button big ripple-effect">Export to Excel</a>`

Route: `Route::get('job/export/{id}', 'JobsController@export');`

> Give me Empty Excel.

Comment: Is there an error?  What happens when you try this?

Comment: Give me Empty Excel.

Comment: please add the route declaration

Comment: @dparoli updated

Comment: I think you have to write an exporter class with Maatwebsite\Excel, I don't think you can pass a collection directly to the download function, please check the docs on how to use that class: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/

Comment: I want to export from a query (Export queries with automatic chunking for better performance.)

Comment: Full explanation is here. It helps your purpose. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-export-database-table-to-excel-file-in-laravel?page=1

Comment: [This helps me a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56104727/laravel-excel-3-1-add-extra-rows-betweem-iterations) hope to help you also

Answer (score 1):

You have not used your **JobExport** Export. You are not passing the data to the JobExport

First make an export using command:

```
php artisan make:export JobExport
```

Your JobExport must have data somewhat like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Exports;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;

class JobExport implements FromView,ShouldAutoSize
{

    use Exportable;

    private $errors  = [];

    public function __construct($error_list){
        $this->errors = $error_list;
    }

    public function view(): View
    {
        return view('exports.job_export_sheet', [
            'errors' => $this->errors,
        ]);
    }
}
```

You can send the data to the export using the below code:

```
return Excel::download(new (new JobExport($query)), 'users.xlsx');
```

After That make a view in resources/views/exports/job_export_sheet

Add the following code in the **job_export_sheet.blade.php**

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Row No.</th>
    <th>Sheet Name</th>
    <th>Row Name</th>
    <th>List Of Errors</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($errors as $key=>$error)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $error[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{ $error[1]}}</td>
        <td>{{ $error[2]}}</td>
        <td>{{ $error[3]}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

The excelsheet with the name **users.xlsx** will get downloaded. The way you are sending **$query** is incorrect

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I'm sorry I already used php artisan make:export JobExport but can't used return view

Comment: You need to use return view and also JobExport in the controller. The way you had done it earlier was wrong.

Comment: Could you tell me please how to return view by id