# Laravel: Too few arguments to function App\Exports\JobExport::__construct(), 0 passed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I'm trying to export to Excel from Query but give me an error

> Too few arguments to function App\Exports\JobExport::__construct(), 0
>   passed and exactly 1 expected

App\Exports:

```
use App\Applyed;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
class JobExport implements FromQuery
{
 use Exportable;
public function __construct(int $id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
    return $this;
}

public function query()
{
    return Applyed::query()->whereId('job_id', $this->id);
}
}
```

Controller:

```
 public function export($id)
{  
    return (new JobExport)->forId($id)->download('invoices.xlsx');
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('job/export/{id}', 'JobsController@export');
```

Blade:

```
<a href="{{url('job/export',$job->id)}}" class="button big ripple-effect">Export to Excel</a>
```

Comment: [This helps me a lot.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56104727/laravel-excel-3-1-add-extra-rows-betweem-iterations) hope it's helps you also.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return (new JobExport)->forId($id)->download('invoices.xlsx');
```

Into

```
return (new JobExport($id))->download('invoices.xlsx');
```

Or remove the `$id` constructor argument if you want to use the `forId()` setter instead.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I used return (new JobExport($id))->download('invoices.xlsx'); but give me empty excel :(